# Symfony 4 Installation Hwioauth Bundle

Tags: symfony4, hwioauthbundle

i want to install Hwioauth Bundle in Symfony 4.1. 
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle.

**Installation:**

```
0.6 with support for Symfony >=2.8
0.5 with support for Symfony >=2.3,<4.0
0.4 with support for Symfony >=2.3,<3.0
0.3 with support for Symfony >=2.1,<2.7
```

I didn't see any installation or document for symfony4.1 here. Only for 3.x version. Anyone can help me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

You need use 0.6 release [HwiOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).
My config. On Symfony 4.1

ProjectName/config/hwi_oauth.yaml

`hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [main]
    resource_owners:
        google:
            type: google
            client_id: "%env(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)%"
            client_secret: "%env(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)%"
            scope: "email profile"
            options:
                access_type: offline
                display: popup`

ProjectName/config/security.yaml on main firewall add this

`oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    google: /login/check-google
                login_path: /login
                use_forward: false
                failure_path: /login
                success_handler: App\Security\Authentication\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: App\Security\User\UserProvider`

P.S I do not use [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html), but if you use it, put it in (oauth_user_provider).

Comment: First, Thank for answer me. I will try it.

Comment: @chinhnguyen let me now if you have any questions.

Comment: I can't try that code now because i leave the company and don't have PC. I will try it later. Thanks again for support, have a nice day bro :D

Comment: @OwaisAslam yes i now use on symfony 4.2

Comment: @ЙосяГисем Do you know is there any other way to get linkedin profile data? this is a big bundle and I don't need these all funcationalities.  I tried linkedinbundle but I couldn't find symfony 4 configurations there.

Comment: @OwaisAslam sorry i don't now because  i use more function.

Comment: @ЙосяГисем installing on symfony 4.2 but getting this error. 
` Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "oauth" listener on "main"
!!    firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider.
!!`

Comment: @OwaisAslam you add oauth block on security-> firewalls -> main ? in file ProjectName/config/security.yaml

Comment: @ЙосяГисем in projectName/config/packages/security.yaml in firewall main.

Comment: @OwaisAslam please send your config  security and hwi_oauth.